# Vue (similar) components and reusability

Tags: vuejs2, components, dry, reusability

I have a 3 vue components they all do similar stuff.

They all output a square (100px x 100px) div with a value inside it, they are different colours.

- component 1 (red) takes 2 values and outputs a percentage.
- component 2 (blue) takes a float value and rounds it up to the next int
- component 3 (green) takes 3 values and finds the mean.

Is there a way to combine this into one reusable component. They share a template and have similar methods.

What would be the best way to DRY this up a bit.

Comment: The interface of 3 components are different. I prefer using different component for each.

Comment: Thanks, that sounds reasonable to me.  It would create an overly complicated component instead of 3 very simple ones.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what parts are overlapping. You should likely be individual components, but they can extend a base component if they reuse same template, or they could utilise mixins to share functinality.

here is a link that goes into more detail https://alligator.io/vuejs/composing-components/

> **Extends** allow you to extend a single other component, with your
>   component’s options taking higher priority over the parent
>   component’s. This means, for example, that if both the parent and your
>   component contain a created() hook, your component’s created() hook
>   will be called first, then the parent’s.
>
> **Mixins** are even cooler. They allow you to extend multiple component
>   definitions. Using mixins, it’s simple to provide reusable methods and
>   data across any number of your components.

I should point out though that the use of mixins is controversial. The react community has a pretty strong stance https://medium.com/@dan_abramov/mixins-are-dead-long-live-higher-order-components-94a0d2f9e750  however creating HOCs in vue is a bit trickier